# SQLAlchemy ArgumentError property of that name exists on mapper 'Mapper[Order(Order)]

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, aiogram

I have three models: User, Profile and Order. Every User can have only one Profile, so I'm using one to one relationship, but every User may have a lit of orders, so I'm using a ForeignKey relationship here. I used `backref` method to relate tables with each other, but when I run the code it shows me that mistake `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Error creating backref 'user' on relationship 'User.order_id': property of that name exists on mapper 'Mapper[Order(Order)]'` 
I google the answer and still can't understand what's wrong, explain to me, please. My models:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'User'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tg_id = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    order_id = relationship('Order', backref='user', lazy=True, cascade='all, delete-orphan')
    profile_id = relationship('Profile', backref='user', uselist=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'User {self.name}: {self.tg_id}'

class Profile(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Profile'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('User.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.tg_id}: {self.nickname}'

class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Order'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('User.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.id} + {self.title}'
```

Comment: Hi @Art, it is telling us the attribute user has been occupied when it tries to create one. based on document, you should change this line in order and profile class from user to user_id, full text is "user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('User.id'))", have a try. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/backref.html

Comment: HI @Art, could you share the full new error message?

Comment: @jonathan200, thanks, it works fine! But why it was occupied then?

Comment: Hi @Art, glad to hear it works. I put it in a formal answer with explanation. read it to see whether it makes sense to you. In short, your foreign key attribute in order object was also called user, that created a conflict when backref method tries to create its own user attribute for backref object.

Answer (score 1):

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Error creating backref 'user' on
> relationship 'User.order_id': property of that name exists on mapper
> 'Mapper[Order(Order)]'

The error states that the attribute user has been occupied when it tried to create reference attribute user in order object.

That is because attribute user has been used for foreign key attribute in order object. but backref now want to user as attribute name for backref ojbect. In general, foreign key attribute should name as user_id in order object.

See example config on [backref and backpopulates](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/backref.html) documents.

The following change should be made in the ORM class config:

1. in order class, change user attribute to user_id attribute

```
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('User.id'))
```

2. in profile class, change user attribute to user_id attribue

```
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('User.id'))
```

3. in user class, change order_id attribute to order attribute, change profile_id attribute to profile attribute.

```
    order = relationship('Order', backref='user', lazy=True, cascade='all, delete-orphan')
    profile = relationship('Profile', backref='user', uselist=False)
```

Here is the updated config:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'User'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tg_id = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    order = relationship('Order', backref='user', lazy=True, cascade='all, delete-orphan')
    profile = relationship('Profile', backref='user', uselist=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'User {self.name}: {self.tg_id}'

class Profile(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Profile'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('User.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.tg_id}: {self.nickname}'

class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Order'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('User.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.id} + {self.title}'
```